# NestJs Multer upload file with fileFilter cause infinite pending

Tags: upload, nestjs, multer, filefilter

i have an issue witch Multer and NestJS to upload file. I try to check if file already exist to return an error. it's working well but if i try to re-upload a file after that, i have infinite pending request. (if i remove the filter i have no problem but i overwrite the file)

here my controller code:

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @UseGuards(RolesGuard)
  @Role('SCENARISTE')
  @Post('upload/sound')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', {
    storage: diskStorage({
      destination: 'files/sounds',
      filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        return callback(null, file.originalname);
      }
    }),
    fileFilter: (req, file, callback) => {
      if (existsSync(join('files/sounds', file.originalname))) {
        return callback(new NotAcceptableException(ErrorType.FILE_ALREADY_EXIST), false);
      } else {
        return callback(null, true);
      }
    },
  }))
  uploadSound(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
    const fileReponse = {
      originalname: file.originalname,
      mimetype: file.mimetype,
      filename: file.filename,
      size: file.size,
      destination: file.destination,
      fieldname: file.fieldname,
      path: file.path
    };
    return fileReponse;
  }
```

thank in advance for your help

may be the first request not close/stop correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

According to Multer's [documantion](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#filefilter), whenever you want to throw an error, you must call the callback by passing the first argument with an error, and leave the second argument or pass the `false` value.

Hence, try to change your code like this:

```js
return callback(new NotAcceptableException(ErrorType.FILE_ALREADY_EXIST));
```

Comment: when i remove the second argument i got and error: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554) multer-options.interface.d.ts(50, 40): An argument for 'acceptFile' was not provided.

Comment: What about passing `false` as the second argument?

Comment: Damn sorry i must put false but i was trying true when i post the code... it's not working true or false